# How to move files into subdirectories segregated by date

Tags: bash, files, find, mv

I have a large directory of files last modified over the past several years through now. Is there an easy command or commands I can type one-time in an interactive bash shell that can create subdirectories with the name of each subdirectory being a four-digit year, and move respective files into each subdirectory when I cannot rely on any information in the file name regarding the age of the file, and finally verify everything I ran worked properly and I didn't lose any files or data?

For example given this completely fake example:

```
$ cd ~/Documents
$ ls -lhrt
...
-rw-r--r--  4 user   user    4.0K Jun 29  2017 oldfile.txt
-rw-r--r--  4 user   user    4.0K May 15  2018 2018file.md
-rw-r--r--  4 user   user    4.0K Apr 14  2019 04.dat
-rw-r--r--  4 user   user    4.0K Jul 21  2019 somepage.html
drw-r--r--  4 user   user    4.0K Jul 21  2019 somepage_files
-rw-r--r--  4 user   user    4.0K Mar 13  2020 march.dat
-rw-r--r--  4 user   user    4.0K Feb 12 18:03 file02.dat
-rw-r--r--  4 user   user    4.0K Oct 11 18:03 OctReport.txt
```

When I'm done, I want to end up with the following:

```
$ cd ~/Documents
$ find .
.
./2017
./2017/oldfile.txt
./2018
./2018/2018file.md
./2019
./2019/04.dat
./2019/somepage.html
./2019/somepage_files
./2019/somepage_files/...
./2020
./2020/march.dat
./2021
./2021/file02.dat
./2021/OctReport.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop with `date` to get the modification year of each file (here assuming GNU `date` or compatible for its `-r` option) to create the directories with. Each file will then be moved to their respective directory.

```
for file in *; do
    [ ! -L "$file" ] &&
      dir_name=$(date -r "$file" +%Y) &&
      mkdir -p "$dir_name" &&
      mv -- "$file" "$dir_name"
done
```

Comment: Since multiple files will map to the same directory and you are doing `mkdir` for each file, you are llikely to end up with lots of "cannot create directory: File exists" error messages from `mkdir`. You should probably either check if the directory exists already or use `mkdir -p` to avoid the error message.

Comment: Thanks, that is cleaner than redirecting those errors to `/dev/null`.

Comment: I stated I wanted directories included as well, so I ran without the `[ -f "$file" ] &&` but then discovered I had a couple symlinks I wanted excluded, so I replaced with `[ \! -L "$file" ] &&` and it appears to have worked as expected.

Comment: @jia103 My initial answer did in fact include directories before it was edited by Stéphane but it did not exclude symlinks as that was not noted in the question. Regardless, nice to hear you got it working as expected.

Comment: @jia103 Sorry about that, I added the `[ -f "$file" ]` to avoid moving the year directories themselves. Note that the modification time of a directory doesn't reflect the age of the content of the files in them, only the last time a file was added / removed / renamed in them. You could do `[[ $file != [12][0-9][0-9][0-9] ]]` to exclude the year directories themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Using the **perl** `rename` utility (not to be confused with `rename` from util-linux or any other `rename`):

```
$ rename -n -e 'BEGIN {use POSIX};
                next unless -f $_;
                my $Y = strftime "%Y", localtime((stat $_)[9]);
                mkdir $Y unless -d $Y;
                s=^=$Y/=' *
rename(04.dat, 2019/04.dat)
rename(2018file.md, 2018/2018file.md)
rename(file02.dat, 2021/file02.dat)
rename(march.dat, 2020/march.dat)
rename(OctReport.txt, 2021/OctReport.txt)
rename(oldfile.txt, 2017/oldfile.txt)
rename(somepage_files, 2019/somepage_files)
rename(somepage.html, 2019/somepage.html)
```

The `-n` option makes this a dry-run.  Remove it (or replace with `-v` for verbose output) when you're sure it's going to do what you want.  e.g.

```
$ find . -type f -ls
   864326      9 drwxr-xr-x   2 cas      cas            10 Dec 22 18:08 .
   863863      1 -rw-r--r--   1 cas      cas             0 Oct 11 18:03 ./OctReport.txt
   863999      1 -rw-r--r--   1 cas      cas             0 Jul 21  2019 ./somepage_files
   864123      1 -rw-r--r--   1 cas      cas             0 Mar 13  2020 ./march.dat
   863997      1 -rw-r--r--   1 cas      cas             0 May 15  2018 ./2018file.md
   864122      1 -rw-r--r--   1 cas      cas             0 Apr 14  2019 ./04.dat
   863862      1 -rw-r--r--   1 cas      cas             0 Feb 12  2021 ./file02.dat
   863998      1 -rw-r--r--   1 cas      cas             0 Jul 21  2019 ./somepage.html
   863996      1 -rw-r--r--   1 cas      cas             0 Jun 29  2017 ./oldfile.txt


$ rename -v -e 'BEGIN {use POSIX}; next unless -f $_; my $Y = strftime "%Y", localtime((stat $_)[9]); mkdir $Y unless -d $Y; s=^=$Y/=' *
04.dat renamed as 2019/04.dat
2018file.md renamed as 2018/2018file.md
file02.dat renamed as 2021/file02.dat
march.dat renamed as 2020/march.dat
OctReport.txt renamed as 2021/OctReport.txt
oldfile.txt renamed as 2017/oldfile.txt
somepage_files renamed as 2019/somepage_files
somepage.html renamed as 2019/somepage.html


$ find . -type f -ls
   863996      1 -rw-r--r--   1 cas      cas             0 Jun 29  2017 ./2017/oldfile.txt
   863862      1 -rw-r--r--   1 cas      cas             0 Feb 12  2021 ./2021/file02.dat
   863863      1 -rw-r--r--   1 cas      cas             0 Oct 11 18:03 ./2021/OctReport.txt
   863999      1 -rw-r--r--   1 cas      cas             0 Jul 21  2019 ./2019/somepage_files
   864122      1 -rw-r--r--   1 cas      cas             0 Apr 14  2019 ./2019/04.dat
   863998      1 -rw-r--r--   1 cas      cas             0 Jul 21  2019 ./2019/somepage.html
   864123      1 -rw-r--r--   1 cas      cas             0 Mar 13  2020 ./2020/march.dat
   863997      1 -rw-r--r--   1 cas      cas             0 May 15  2018 ./2018/2018file.md
```

see `perldoc -f stat` and `perldoc -f localtime` for details on those perl functions.  Details on `strftime()` can be found in `perldoc POSIX`.

BTW, `rename` can take filenames as args on the command line, or from stdin (even NUL-separated filenames if you use rename's `-0` option, which is useful when dealing with filenames containing newlines and other annoying characters).  See `man rename`.

Answer (score 1):

`find` may be of great use here - note that `printf` needs GNU-`find`:

1. Create necessary directories

   `find -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -printf '%TY\n' | sort -u | xargs mkdir`
2. Move files accordingly:

   `find -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -printf '%f\0%TY/%f\0' | xargs -0 -l2 mv --`

Using NUL-delimited names in step 2 makes this approach very robust towards filenames with spaces, newlines, etc.

When it comes to including directories (your text says files, but your example includes directories), one would have to exclude the year-named directories in step 2:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 ! -name '[12][0129][0-9][0-9]' -printf '%f\0%TY/%f\0' | xargs -0 -l2 mv
```

... assuming that you have no files older than the year 1000 or newer than 2999, hopefully.

---

Maybe you also want to update the age of the directories? Then run:

```
for dir in [12][0129][0-9][0-9] ; do
   touch -d ${dir}-01-01 $dir
done
```

That way the age of the directory is set to first of Jan of the respective year and future, date-based searches are simplified.

Comment: *`-printf(%TY\n)`* What shell syntax is that? Also `[1,2]` matches on `1`, `,` or `2`. `-printf` is GNU-specific.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas `[1,2]` - mixup with shell brace expansion thanks & corrected. `-printf` being GNU -> I was not aware, good to mention. Regarding the syntax: I cannot follow your question? `%Tx` is last modification time in format `x`, `Y` being 4-digit year. `\n` just to separate the entries for `xargs` - well knowing that in `YYYY` there are no dangerous characters (if executed in the current dir).

Comment: If that's meant to be `bash` syntax, it should be `-printf '%TY\n'`, not `-printf(%TY\n)`. `!-name` should be `! -name`. `mv` should be `mv --`